# Akka: What happens when you tell an ActorRef and it expects you to ask?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, future

I have the following:

`val future = myActor ? Message`

And in my actor my receive message has something like this:

`sender ! Response`

If I do the following and ignore the response, is there any negative impact?

`myActor ! Message`

Maybe I'm just missing where it says this in the documentation.  Is it like a method that returns a value and the caller doesn't assign the return value to anything?  If I make that call from another actor is there going to be some weird threading issue or memory leaks that result from it?  My unit tests don't seem to be affected but it's kind of a contrived.  I'm hoping I'm just over-thinking the problem and maybe I can't find the answer because it's a stupid question that no one in their right mind asks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With ask pattern `Response` is received by temporary light-weight actor ([`PromiseActorRef`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/AskSupport.scala#L160)).

In case of `myActor ! Message` there should be implicit `ActorRef` in scope. `Response` will be sent to this implicit `ActorRef`. This message will not be garbage-collected until you explicitly read it.

If there is no implicit `ActorRef` in scope `Actor.noSender` is used and `Response` will be forwarded to system's deadLetters.

If you make that call from another actor this `Response` will be delivered to message box of this another actor.

Comment: Wow, a quick unit test verified this.  I wasn't able to get it in the deadLetters but I'm sure that was more a matter of the way I was doing it than the correctness of your assertion.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mike: It's from documentation. `!` method: `def !(message: Any)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Unit `; [`noSender`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.0/#akka.actor.Actor$): `Default placeholder (null) used for "!" to indicate that there is no sender of the message, that will be translated to the receiving system's deadLetters.`.