# Akka ActorRef being created with null actor

Tags: scala, null, akka

I have an Akka `Actor` (in Scala) that looks like this:

```
object MyActor {
  def apply (system: ActorSystem, parm1: Int, parm2: Int, parm3: ActorRef): ActorRef = {
    system.actorOf (Props (classOf[MyActor], parm1, parm2, parm3), "myactor")
  }
}

class MyActor (parm1: Int, parm2: Int, parm3: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    [...bunch of cases, ending with _...]
  }
}
```

Actually, I have several `Actor`s that follow that pattern.  But this one, when I create an instance like this:

```
val myActorRef = MyActor (system, 3, 4, helperRef)
```

refuses to see any of the messages I send it.  Breakpoints in `MyActor.receive ()` are never hit.

I poked around a little in the debugger and found a field called `myActorRef._cellDoNotCallMeDirectly._actor`.  For all my other actors, this field contains an instance of the relevant `Actor` subclass, implying that in this case it should contain an instance of `MyActor`.

However, in this case, that field is `null`.

My suspicion is that this has something to do with the fact that the `.receive ()` isn't seeing any messages.  I'm surprised that there aren't `NullPointerException`s flying around, but there aren't.

Does a `null` value in this field mean anything in particular?  Am I screwing up somehow?

Thanks,
Dan Wiebe

Comment: from where are you calling `myActorRef ! msg`. In the sense that is the expression being called from with-in an Actor or from somewhere else?

Comment: Probably the actor fails to initialize for some reason. Do you have any code in the constructor, or the `preStart` method? Did you check the log for initialization issues? Do you create multiple actors of this kind? Because the name is always the same and that is not allowed.

Comment: Might be a possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094145/akka-what-happens-when-you-tell-an-actorref-and-it-expects-you-to-ask The question there is irrelevant, consider the answer.

Comment: I can't see any clues to the answer in the question. However, I see here a reflection is used to construct an instance of MyActor.
Why don't you use `Props(new MyActor(parm1, parm2, parm3))`. It allows you to go without reflection.

Comment: @ArseniyZhizhelev That method is deprecated in 2.2 to prevent closing over non-serializable values.

Answer (score 1):

Try notifying other actor(s) of your actor's existence in its `preStart` method, by sending a message to them, instead of relying on the `ActorRef` created when you create the actor. This should sort out any concurrency bugs that might be preventing your application from working.

If that doesn't fix it, enable full logging so you can see if the messages are being sent and received correctly.